# Getting name(s) of FOLDER containing a specific SUBSTRING from the C:Temp directory in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, directory, substring

Guys as the title says it I have to get the names of FOLDERS having a particular (user indicated) sub string.

I have a text box where the user will input the wanted sub string.
and I am using the codes below to achieve my goal.

```
 string name = txtNameSubstring.Text;
            string[] allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Temp");//Change path to yours
            foreach (string file in allFiles)
            {
                if (file.Contains(name))
                {
                    cblFolderSelect.Items.Add(allFiles);
                    // MessageBox.Show("Match Found : " + file);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No files found");
                }
            }
```

It does not work.
When I trigger it,only the message box appears.
Help ?

Comment: If you're looking for folders, why are you searching through files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [appropriate API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w.aspx) to let the framework filter the directories.

```cs
var pattern = "*" + txtNameSubstring.Text + "*";
var directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Temp", pattern);
```

Comment: I also added a for each loop.Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Because the `MessageBox` will appear for the first path that does not contain the substring

You could use `Linq` to get the folders, but you will need to use `GetDirectories` not `GetFiles`

```
string name = txtNameSubstring.Text;
var allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Temp").Where(x => x.Contains(name));//

if (!allFiles.Any())
{
   MessageBox.Show("No files found");
}

cblFolderSelect.Items.AddRange(allFiles);
```

Comment: i get this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: sorry my bad, I wrote that in notepad, it should be `var`, I have updated

Comment: still no result in the combobox i am getting only one item like <System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator`1[System.String]>

Comment: try foreach instaed of AddRange, im not familiar with asp.net so perhaps the combobox is different, anyway `allFiles` should contain your folders :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to have the message box inside the loop.

```
string name = txtNameSubstring.Text;
string[] allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Temp");//Change path to yours
foreach (string file in allFiles)
{
   if (file.Contains(name))
   {
      cblFolderSelect.Items.Add(file);
      // MessageBox.Show("Match Found : " + file);
   }
}
if(cblFolderSelect.Items.Count==0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("No files found");
}
```

(Assuming `cblFolderSelect` was empty before this code runs)

As you currently have it, you're deciding whether to show the message box for *each* file that you examine. So if the first file doesn't match, you'll be told "No files found" even though the next file might match.

(I've also changed the `Add` to add the individual file that matches, not all of the files (for which one or more matches))